# Spring Boot Test: Inject different Resources for each unit tests

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, spring-test, spring-boot-test

I created a @SpringBootTest-annotated class to test the HTTP responses of a REST endpoint.

I compare each HTTP JSON response with the content of a Resource.

```
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class SampleApplicationTests {

  @Autowired
  private MockMvc mockMvc;

  @Value("classpath:data/result1.json")
  private Resource result1;

  @Value("classpath:data/result2.json")
  private Resource result2;

  @Test
  public void test1() {
    mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.
        get("/api/persons")).
        andExpect(MockMvcResutMatchers.status().isOk()).
        andExpect(MockMvcResutMatchers.content().json(asString(result1)));    
  }

  @Test
  public void test2() {
    mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.
        get("/api/persons/1")).
        andExpect(MockMvcResutMatchers.status().isOk()).
        andExpect(MockMvcResutMatchers.content().json(asString(result2)));
  }

  ...

  private static String asString(Resource resource) {
    try {
      return IOUtils.toString(resource.getInputStream());
    } catch (IOException e) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException(e);
    }
  }
}
```

I would like to know if there is a more elegant way to inject resources at the level of each test.

I know I can use `ResourceLoader` to load resources for each test:

```
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class SampleApplicationTests {

  @Autowired
  private ResourceLoader resourceLoader = null;

  @Test
  public void test1() {
    String result = asString(resourceLoader.getResource("classpath:data/result1.json");

    mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.
        get("/api/persons")).
        andExpect(MockMvcResutMatchers.status().isOk()).
        andExpect(MockMvcResutMatchers.content().json(result));
  }
  ...
}
```

But I would like to know if there is an Annotation that allows to load a resource for each test.
Something like the following:

```
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class SampleApplicationTests {

  @Test
  @TestResource("classpath:data/result1.json")
  public void test1(Resource result) {
    mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.
        get("/api/persons")).
        andExpect(MockMvcResutMatchers.status().isOk()).
        andExpect(MockMvcResutMatchers.content().json(result));
  }
  ...
}
```

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SpringBootTest` is annotated with `@SpringExtension` which resolves arguments for method parameters as well:

```java
  @Test
  public void test1(@Value("classpath:data/result1.json") Resource result1) {
    // ...
  }

  @Test
  public void test2(@Value("classpath:data/result2.json") Resource result2) {
    // ...
  }
```